# Get isolated storage for assembly

Tags: c#, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I need at the end of installation create isolated storage for assembly of my application during installation to load initial settings for it. it isn't loaded during installation but I know name and full path of it.

I would like to use this method:

```
 IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null, **assembly param**);
```

But I don't know what to put in **assembly param** in documentation it has several overloads but I can't to call it correctly.

When application works we initialize isolated storage like:

```
IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForAssembly()
```

So I need to get the same folder but during installation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The right way in this case to call the IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore like this:

```
var identity = new System.Security.Policy.Url(@"file:///fullpatch to your dll");
IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.User, null, identity);
```

Knowing path of assembly we can initialize isolated storage for assembly.